# drawing under icons on desktop

Tags: windows-vista, windows-xp, desktop, hook

I wrote a program who paints widget on desktop wallpaper, under desktop icons, and all was good.
But I reveal a strange bug - my program was not works on some other computers - they displays
the same desktop without widget after start.

So, have anybody any expirience, some knowledge in this area? Please, help me! :)

(I can't find any computers near, where widget not works, in my computer all works well.
I wrote a lot of test programs, whose tries draw anything on desktop with rather methods,
but test displays nothing too in my friends computers.)

Drawing method:

I wrote a dll, who finds desktop window (progman->child->child ))
and creates a hook and install own window procedure for desktop.
In window procedure i hook WM_ERASEBKGND:

```
case WM_ERASEBKGND:
  HDC hdc = (HDC)wparam;
  PaintDesktop(hdc);
  WidgetPaint(hdc);
  return 1;
```

// I skip in this code getting and setting clipping areas for fast drawing.
(I tried all combinations with clipping and without clipping)

And in tests I also trying to paint widget in WM_PAINT message with same results -- all already works at me, but works not at all my friends.

upd: I solved it! :)

Comment: Does your code work in Windows XP and *not* work in Windows Vista or Windows 7?

Comment: Yes, my code works in XP and Windows Vista.
But copmletely not works in Windows 7. In Windows 7, I suppose,
its a protection mechanism. (I can't even list DLLs which loaded in explorer.exe process)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what was the fix?

Comment: When solving your own problems, please remember to post the fix as well, and accept your own answer.

Comment: Would appreciate you post the answer to this question, interested in seeing what it was.

Comment: thanks for intesert :)
I wrote answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it!
It's simple was a 64-bit machines)
So I compile my code for 64-bit and widget start work pretty good!

And, also -

```
PaintDesktop(hdc);
```

will produce very bright wallpaper in Windows7 (and Vista) with Aero.
(User's wallpaper comes brighten).
Must be

```
CallWindowProc(OldWndProc, WM_ERASEBKGND, wparam, lparam);
```

Cause of this - Aero treats PaintDesktop() as usual paint (over virtual screen wallpaper, that is the same as on desktop) with color summation.

Regards! :)

Comment: I'm just trying to write a similar thing. I want to display an image beneath the desktop icons. I'm not a windows programming expert so I have some hard time with this. Could you please post somewhere source code for your widget?

Comment: Can you post a more detailed answer. I am curious how you paint under desktop icons.