# How to put a form behind desktop icons?

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, icons, desktop

How would you put a WinForms form behind desktop icons but in front of the wallpaper? To make the desktop the form's parent, I use:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

    IntPtr desktopHandle = (IntPtr)FindWindow("Progman", null);
    WallForm wallWindow = new WallForm();//WinForms Form

    ...

    private void SwitchParent()
    {
        wallWindow.Show();
        SetParent(wallWindow.Handle, desktopHandle);
        //wallWindow.SendToBack();
    }
```

This works, but it puts the form in front of the desktop icons. If I call SendToBack on my form, it disappears, presumably behind the wallpaper. How could I get the form to be between the icons and the desktop background?

Comment: You could save your window as a bitmap as set as the Desktop background, But I assume you want a working application, in that case its not possible.

Comment: What's the use case for this? Perhaps there's a better way to accomplish the same goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe that this is possible to do.  The desktop window is a single window that renders the desktop image and the icons, so there is no way to insert your window between the desktop image and the icons.

Short of writing a shell replacement that handled the background image and desktop icons differently (a major development task with many hurdles) the only other option I can think of is to hook into the desktop's events and intercept WM_ERASEBKGND or similar to do your own drawing.  (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411718/drawing-under-icons-on-desktop) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835175/replacing-desktop-wallpaper-draw-on-the-desktop) for more info.)

Unfortunately this won't let you put a WinForm behind the icons, only an image.  You'd have to handle a lot of other windows messages to simulate an actual form.  It's a major undertaking regardless.

Comment: There are programs that can draw under the icons. So it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution to this problem, at least for Windows 8. I postet it in form of an article on CodeProject, so you can read about it here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/856020/Draw-behind-Desktop-Icons-in-Windows

This works for simple drawing, windows forms, wpf, directx, etc. The solution presented in that article is only for Windows 8.